# How is cyclic time series data stationary

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series

As we know seasonality in data which basically means cycle is not stationary data. Then I see some examples online where I can see clear cycle but still it's mentioned as stationary data, I'm not able to understand the clear version when it'll be consider as cycle and when it'll be not. Below I have attach picture where one claims to be seasonal and other's not but I can't distinguish them.
This is not stationary!
[image]

This is stationary! But I can clearly see cycle or seasonality here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [Forecasting: Principles and Practice by Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos](https://otexts.com/fpp3/stationarity.html#stationarity), time series with trends, or seasonality, are not stationary. On the other hand, a time series with no trend or seasonality might show cyclic behavior. This would be the case if cycles do not have a fixed length and one cannot be sure where for example the peaks will be.